# Extracting dependencies from .classpath to pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build-tools

I would like to know if there is a way to create a Maven dependency in the pom.xml from the dependencies specified in the .classpath file. For example:
If this is mentioned in the .classpath :

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="SF_JAVA_EXT_LIBS/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
```

I would like some programmatic way to append a text to the pom.xml such that it looks like this:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
<version>1.2.17</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
<type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

P.S. I am writing a simple Java program to do the mavenization, but i would prefer some more deterministic and generalizable way than using string manipulation to do the above. Some lookup library maybe?

Comment: Simply no. Cause the dependencies are in the pom file and the pom file contains the "truth"...Simply add the deps from .classpath into the pom file? Where is the problem...

Comment: because the maven file, relies on the dependency structure like mentioned above, and the classpath doesnt have that

Comment: Classpath will have entry of each jar directly used by project and also have jars that are indirectely required by those jars. However in pom you need to specify the top level jars and maven will take care of transitive dependencies.

Comment: I know that, thats why the question was, is there any lookup/library api/method of sorts in which i can feed the name of the jar file, and get the maven dependency as a response?